# Is it possible to know if an outgoing call is accepted in Android

Tags: android

In my app I have to detect if the outgoing call is accepted or disconnected or ringing. I went through these posts:

- [Is there any way to know if an outgoing call is accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668383/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-an-outgoing-call-is-accepted?rq=1)
- [Cannot detect when outgoing call is answered in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134331/cannot-detect-when-outgoing-call-is-answered-in-android)
- [how to get the state for outgoing calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213659/how-to-get-the-state-for-outgoing-calls)
- [How to identify the ringing state of outgoing call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910570/how-to-identify-the-ringing-state-of-outgoing-call-in-android)
- [Out going call answered state in Android 2.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948748/out-going-call-answered-state-in-android-2-2?rq=1)

But none of these posts give a proper answer. I used the Android internal class `com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager`, but I'm only getting whether the phone state is idle.

Answer (score 0):

Formally you cannot do that, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940677/how-to-detect-the-event-when-receiver-accept-my-outgoing-call), but there is a workaround that I'm using:
You can save your last status and use it to identify when an outgoing call moves from off-hook to idle, which means that the call was hung up or accepted. So, to know which it is, you can check if the call still alive and if so you can tell that the call was answered and execute your code.

For example:

```
// 0 --> 1 || 0 --> 2
if (   laststate == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
    && (   state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
        || state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK))
{
}
else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
{
}

if (   laststate == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
    && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
{
}

laststate = state;
```

Comment: Actually how i will use the lastState variable.means i have to store it statically or in sharedpreference..can u plz tell me in deeply?

Comment: This is not my answer.This condition doesn't satisfies to get the ringing state or accepted state..

Comment: how would this work if user had a callwaiting though ?